# if $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n\right)=L$ than $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{b_n}\right)=\frac{1}{L}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

it's begginer question i know but very important for me to understand:
$b_n\:\ne 0,\:L\ne 0$
if  $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n\right)=L$ than $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{b_n}\right)=\frac{1}{L}$?

I try to prove it like this:
from the question we know that by definition : $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \forall n>N , |b_{n}-L| < \epsilon $

so we choose some $\epsilon$ >0.
Now we need to show that exist N1 such that for every n>N1, $\left|\frac{1}{b_n}\:-\:\frac{1}{L}\right|<\:\epsilon $ right?

how do i continue from here?

what i'm looking for, that is the real question...
if someone can guide me step by step it will be awesome! tnx!

Comment: Remember $L \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

If $b_n \rightarrow L \neq 0$, then $b_n^{-1} \rightarrow L^{-1}.$

We have

$$|b_n^{-1}- L^{-1}| = \frac{|b_n - L|}{|b_n||L|}.$$

If $(b_n)$ converges then it is bounded and $|b_n| > K > 0$ for $n$ sufficently large -- if the limit is non-zero.

Note that $||b_n| - |L|| \leq |b_n - L|< |L|/2$ for $n$ sufficiently large and we can take $K = |L|/2$.

Since $b_n \rightarrow L,$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that if $n > N$, then

$$|b_n - L| < K|L|\epsilon,$$

and

$$|b_n^{-1}- L^{-1}| < \frac{|b_n - L|}{K|L|} <\epsilon.$$